# Xcode is unbearably slow (and lies). Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My Xcode compiles are taking longer and longer.

Each time I compile it claims it's compiling one file in the Activity window even though I would not have editede it and it has no dependence on the files I'm editing. In the Build window it claims it's compiling another file (the right one).

I have tried cleaning, precompiled headers are in place etc..

This is Xcode 3.2.2

Why is this happening?

Comment: @Joe Blow. It's only doing this on the one project. Other projects compile fast

Comment: You may want to try this simple trick:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which hard disk is your project on?  Could it be a slow drive and/or a full disk kind of issue?  I presume its not a networked drive...

What does the Activity Monitor show - is the machine 100% busy CPU-wise or not?

Comment: Very close answer (in retrospect). I discovered the hard way that it was a dead drive. It was having problems reading certain sectors and thus very very slowv.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I tracked it down to a choppy/really slow Internet connection. Disabling the internet connection by shutting off the wi-fi would make the compiling fast again. The final solution was to stop using my neighbour's wifi and get my own (<- Joke ... not really ... jaja :/)

I'm not sure what is XCode doing over the Internet connection, but with a poor connection some sort of timeout seemed make the building process VERY slow.

This may not be your problem but it is easy enough to test. Cheers!

Comment: Even if that's a problem I will have a bigger problem to deal with. Does apple expect me to code without internet access like in a job test?

Comment: To my experience with Internet and without Internet is fine. The problems I experienced was bad access. My poor connection made the computer believe it had Internet access but connections would timeout frequently.

Comment: Big question is why Xcode is sending data over the internet when you're compiling something.

Comment: XCode supports distributed compilation so it could be the process of looking for other nodes to compile on was slowing it down.

Comment: Disabling the network adapter sped things up for me. Then, after re-enabling the adapter, it stayed at a good speed. thanks Felz

Answer (score 1):

Quite often, problems like this can be fixed by going into your application directory and deleting the BUILD directory. X-Code automatically generates this directory upon compile anyway so you won't lose any data, it just cleans things up a little and MAY allow you to compile quicker in the future.

Source: Alan Cannistraro, Stanford University on one of his iPhone Developement Class Podcasts

Comment: Sorry i couldn't help your issue, there was always a chance that it'd help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and update XCode? (do not read the following : answer needs 30 characters, so I fill my answer with this sentence)