# Can not open archives tab in XCode 4.3 organizer

Tags: xcode, archive, freeze, organizer

The archives tab in my Xcode 4.3 organizer stopped functioning all of sudden.

When I tried to archive a project yesterday, after building successfully, instead of opening archives tab in organizer my Xcode just stopped there. Then I killed and re-opened xcode, but as long as I clicked archives tab in organizer, xcode went frozen again.

I tried the solutions posted in other threads in SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317125/xcodes-4-3-2-organizer-freezes-whenever-i-click-the-archives-tab), delete all the files in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData or [delete all archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588519/xcode-4-archive-results-in-slow-unresponsive-organizer-pngcrush-process-takes),  none of them work.

As long as I archive a project, xcode just went frozen. The only solution worked for me is to keep skilling bash process till xcode stopped hanging.

So any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question. So I contacted Apple support engineer and they told me I need reinstall xcode.

But to reinstall they told me to delete xcode and downloaded it again from mac app store. Because of the pain download experience I had last time, I did not follow that advice. I first moved xcode out of /Application, then run **uninstall-devtools --mode=all** and after that I run xcode again, xcode then prompted me that it needed to install some component. And after that the problem was fixed!!