# refactor function error - "is not part of the build phase of any targets in the Xcode 3 projects in this workspace and so can't be refactored"

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

Trying to rename a function's name via the refactor->rename button in a categoriy's .h file in XCode 4.1 I'm getting this error: (error and body)

UINavigationController+ZG.h is not part of the build phase of any targets in the Xcode 3 projects in this workspace and so can’t be refactored.

Add the file to the build phase of a target in an Xcode 3 project in this workspace, or make a selection in another file.

Not sure what it wants and why it's saying something about xcode 3 when i don't have any xcode 3 projects or anything like that.

Comment: That definitely is a strange message. Note that it is about projects in the workspace. You might be using the workspace feature without knowing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this issue today on a project which don't use workspace at all.
I couldn't get why Xcode behave wired. Auto complete worked, but return some really unrelevant results as my FAMILY NAME (?!) for a class I was working on.

I found it to be a bug in Xcode 4.1 under OS X 10.7.1 along side with other issues i had.
When I reopen my project, the message was gone, refactoring worked as expected and auto-completing worked as well.

**September 2013 Update:**
It seems that this bug is happening also on Xcode 5 & 10.8.5.

Comment: I just got this problem (and sovled it by restarting Xcode). My current project is my first iOS app (usually work in PHP and C#). I'm surprised by how many anomalies in Xcode are fixed by closing and reopening it.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem in Xcode 5 under 10.8.5. Shutting down Xcode and reopening it fixed the problem.

Comment: Still happens in XCode 6.1.1 under OS X 10.10.1   Grrrr

Answer (score 11):

Restarting Xcode did not fix this for me (although it does normally fix a lot of things). I also didn't like the idea of File >> Save As Workspace. As the workspace should already be in my .xcodeproj file, so I didn't want another one. I found another solution that fixed it for me: Window >> Organiser and then Delete Derived Data for my project. Found it mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393413/when-i-try-to-refactor-in-xcode-a-warning-to-add-the-file-to-the-build-phase-of).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get past this error by choosing File >> Save As Workspace.

Answer (score 4):

For me personally it was a combination of things.

1. Deleted derived data from Organizer > projects. (Didn't work after this step)
2. Restarted Xcode.  (Worked after this step)

Answer (score 1):

I have just run into this issue as well. I found that running:

Product->Clean

Fixed the problem, and I can now use refractor again.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced some dead values in project.xcworkspace (Show Package Contents on your Xcode project file) and the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever deleted **.xcworkspace** in Finder? Although the file will be auto-generated by Xcode again, yet its content will be changed. I think that causes your problem. 
I saw [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance) recommends to delete .xcworkspace for the purpose of enhancing build speed. Well, mind the catch.