# When I try to refactor in Xcode, a warning to add the file to the build phase of the target in this workspace appears

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring

I am seeing this message, too often when I try to refactor my code by renaming:

`***.h is not part of the build phase of any targets in this workspace and so can’t be refactored.
Add the file to the build phase of a target in this workspace, or make a selection in another file.`

Sometimes, refactoring works only right after relaunching Xcode and reopen the project. But it's not working afterwards.

Comment: Not succeeding in finding the right solution, I dealt with this situation by repeatedly deleting Derived Data in Organizer > Projects

Comment: I didn't know about that little gem. That's certainly fixed it for me, at least for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not succeeding in finding the right solution, I dealt with this situation by repeatedly deleting Derived Data in Organizer > Projects