# XCode documentation search takes forever 

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

When I type something into the search field in XCode's doc browser, the first couple characters appear and then the spinning beach ball shows up for several seconds before anything happens. Obviously this is very annoying.

Is there some sort of cache that I could clear or other setting that might help?

I'm running XCode 4.2 on OSX 10.7 (Lion).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863282/xcode-4-2-organizer-documentation-unreasonably-slow

Comment: Literally forever.  I upgraded to Lion with Xcode 4.2 two weeks ago, and it's *still* processing my first search.

Answer (score 5):

right, this one is **REALLY_ANNOYING**, a workaround: limit search by clicking the magnifying glass in the search field, pick the doc sets you are interested in, if you can limit to 2 doc sets search time will be reasonable. Check this post: [Xcode 4.2 Organizer - Documentation unreasonably slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863282/xcode-4-2-organizer-documentation-unreasonably-slow)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit, but not really enough to stop cursing at Apple every time I do a doc search... ;)