# Turn off instant search Xcode 4 Documentation

Tags: xcode4

How do I turn off the instant search in Xcode 4's Documentation? Everytime I pause my typing, I have to wait for too long (sometimes 30 seconds, honestly) before I can type some more. If that's how long it takes, I'd rather just hit enter to search.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree! I wish it would wait for enter to search. I don't want to have to not search older documentation so it will delay me less.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have so many documentation sets downloaded or, more importantly, selected to search when you are typing into that Search field... you wouldn't experience the download.

Click on the magnifying glass icon there and you can change "Find Options" to only look at the documentation sets that are most relevant to you (whether Macintosh or iPhone, and whether 10.6 or 10.7, iOS 4 or iOS 5).

(I cribbed my answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863282/xcode-4-2-organizer-documentation-unreasonably-slow)).  Hope this helps you out!