# Stop 'Find' in Xcode from searching dynamically?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to stop Edit>Find in Xcode from searching dynamically as I type?

It drives me nuts to have it interrupt my typing to search....

Thanks.

Comment: @Costique - It seems to do it in Xcode 4.2.1...maybe I'm imagining it?

Comment: I'm seeing this only while searching documentation in the organizer, but, yes, it drives me nuts too. I don't know of any checkboxes to turn off live search, maybe there's a hidden defaults key?

Comment: @Costique Yes, sorry I wasn't specific - it's in the Organizer, not within Xcode proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really annoying behavior. And [as of the last time this question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7863423/927947) there is no way to shut off the live search. But you can speed up the search by selecting some search parameters.

Next to the search magnifying glass icon there is a disclosure triangle if you click on that you will see a menu like this:

[image]

If you click the "Show Find Options" a new menu will appear below the search-bar:

[image]

If you reduce the libraries to be searched to two or so the search-bar will almost be responsive... almost. Reducing languages and match type helps too.

Comment: Thanks - that helps a bit. Sometimes Apple goes a bit too far with their simplicity objectives!

Comment: Agreed. Wait, what? "Agreed" is too short of a comment?

Comment: I have submitted a bug report (enhancement request) to apple. Reference radar 24636856