# Lexical or preprocessor Issue: 'MyViewController.h' file not Found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

When I try to change a view controller name in the `.h` and `.m`, I got this error:

```
Lexical or PreProcessor Issue
'MyViewController.h' file not found.
```

Just for information, the application run correctly although this lexical error.

Comment: Even if you clean the project?

Comment: Yes, even if i clean the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning your build by going into `Product` menu and clicking on `Clean`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing i tried actually, but the error message still there.

Comment: Then try cleaning the workspace like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6356862/1148021