# Can't access public methods of NSObject from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have created this NSObject subtype class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SQLiteManager.h"

@interface clickEventManagement : NSObject{

    SQLiteManager *dbManager;

    NSURLConnection *adsconnection;

    NSMutableData *responseData;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *adsconnection;

-(void) insertClickAdd:(int)zona;

-(void) insertPrintAdd:(int)zona;

-(NSArray*) loadClicks;

@end
```

And I have declared it in the AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "clickEventManagement.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioSessionDelegate>

{

    BOOL firstRun;

    AVPlayer *player;

    clickEventManagement *clickEvent;


}

@property (strong, nonatomic) clickEventManagement *clickEvent;
```

But clickEventMangement methods are not available when I try to implement them in the - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application delegate.

EDITED

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    clickEvent = [[clickEventManagement alloc] init];

    [clickEvent -> "loadClicks" method is not available in the Xcode list


}
```

Same class in other view controllers, declared in the same way, are available.

Thanks!

Comment: They are not available in the method list for this object in Xcode

Comment: Is the code completion not working or are there errors when you try to compile the code with these methods?

Comment: Code works fine, but the issue is that clickEventMangement class methods I need to call are not available. I have edit my question to complete the information. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the code completion is screwy under Xcode - has been for a while on my machine...

Comment: click events? on a touch screen device? really?

Answer (score 0):

If the code compiles, and you mean the autocomplete isn't functioning, I have found success in deleting the xcworkspace file as documented in the accepted solution here: [Xcode 4 - slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance)