# xcode 6 interface builder very slow performance when showing viewcontrollers with constraints

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

I have an problem with Xcode 6 really responding very slowly to user interactions, e.g. editing code, scrolling areas etc. This particularly happens when the interface builder show the view controllers with constraints in the storyboard (4/14 vcs has constraints i just begin the project) additional i use extra monitor.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to improve performance changing xcode options or other way.

My development machine is a MacBook Pro Retina (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with 2.3Ghz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB RAM (1600 MHz DDR3), running OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this same problem where performance plummeted on an external display.

What I ended up discovering was that the external monitor issue was indicating that there was a UIView that interface builder couldn't quite figure out properly for auto-layout.

In my case it was a `UIToolbarBarItem` that contained a `UIView` that contained a `UILabel`. Once I removed the offending `UIToolbarBarItem` the performance issue resolved itself. It went from being completely unusable to smooth scrolling.

You should check if you have a UIView inside something that might cause auto-layout to freak out.

Comment: you are right, in my case it was a UINavigationBar with UIView.

Comment: this also happened to me... but I am not using auto layout... I have dosens of view controllers... xcode uses 95% cpu constantly and it is really unresponsive... I have not detected the problem in my case

Comment: Experienced this on Sierra with Xcode 8.1 and 8.2 beta. Resetting simulated metrics navigation bar/toolbar to None restored my 60FPS sweetness. It is simply insane that such a meaningless setting has such a devastating impact.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how to find the offending view?

Answer (score 18):

Do you use an external monitor? If yes, probably that's the problem. Try moving to the main macbook screen and try again.

That solved the problem for me.

EDIT: sorry, just read you have an external monitor. So yes, move to the main screen and check if that solves the problem.

EDIT 2: seems like Apple fixed the problem, no more issues using my external monitor!

EDIT 3: meh! Problem persists, not sure why it stopped happening, and happens again now.

Comment: you right, when i moving to the main screen the problem solved, but i want to work interface builder in the external monitor (bigger). Any trick for this?... thanks for your response.

Comment: Still no tricks, the problem persists in here. I'm pretty sure is some retina related rendering problem... Awkward and annoying, but we have to deal with it for now.

Comment: @fabrizotus seems like the problem is fixed now, just tried the very same project I had problem the last time we talked and it is gone!

Comment: Thanks @AlanSikora, but the problem persists.

Comment: As @gordontucker indicated, in my case it was a UINavigationBar with UIView.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaargh - what is the difference whether it's displaying on the internal or the external monitor? Especially when the internal one is with a retina resolution, so it shouldn't be the screen size ... But indeed it is a problem, here with an UIToolbar.

Comment: Have you found a solution? 
I was expecting a fix with Xcode 7 and El Capitain but same issue (working well on Retina Display but very slow on external screen). 
My workaround is to set for all ViewControllers in the StoryBoard with a Toolbar to set "none" in Simulated Metrics for "Bottom Bar".

What is strange is with my old "white macBook" it works perfectly with an external screen!

Comment: Still nothing @sebastien, I've been a little far from native iOS since the beginning of the year, got a big project with Ionic. But, last time I tested it tho, still slow, with no apparent fix.

Comment: My storyboard issues were due to Segmented Controls embedded in toolbars. 
I changed the design of my App to put all Segmented Controls out of toolbars and it works well.

Answer (score -2):

Wow, thanks *so* much guys! I was having a huge problem with Xcode being slowed to a crawl while I was modifying interface elements in the interface editor. *All I had to do was uncheck "Use Auto Layout" under the .xib's File Inspector tab*, and it's running faster than ever!

**So if you have any problems with Xcode's interface editor / Interface Builder being slow, just disable Auto Layout for that .xib while you're working on it, then when you're done editing the .xib, as a final step, re-enable it and add your constraints to the items.**

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10520749)

Comment: I did use the word "thanks". I also used other words. Did you read them too, or was this some kind of automated filter response lacking English language recognition? No one suggested in any answer or comment to this question what I suggested in my answer to this question, hence, I provided an original answer to the question. And I stated that executing this answer for myself was helpful in preventing a problem I had that was related to the problem presented in the question, thus making my answer relevant to the question. So I provided a unique answer relevant to the question. Why delete it?

Comment: I can see your point - though even after re-reading your answer it still seems to me as if you were saying you liked (then repeated) somebody else's answer. Would you mind re-phrasing your answer to make this more clear?