# Editing storyboard in Xcode 5 is very slow

Tags: xcode, performance, xcode-storyboard

I have Xcode 5 and storyboard editing is very slow. Each time I start Xcode I get the message:

"The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" had 26 internal inconsistencies that were found and repaired."

and

"Multiple resources have the same name: yellowbutton.png, etc.
The preceding issues may have occurred due to an SCM operation such as merging."

Standard solutions as deleting the workspace file did not help. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Clicking OK for me once resolves the problem :|

Comment: yup...after selecting OK it will never ask again

Comment: Was Xcode also very slow with you guys?

Comment: I repaired but every time I go into a storyboard, beach ball of death for 20-30 seconds .... so annoying !

Comment: I got the same problem, Opening the storyboard makes everything slow down A LOT

Comment: Same problem for me. I have quite a large storyboard but it worked ok in Xcode 4. Xcode 5 is really slow

Comment: same issue. I am running Xcode 5, Mavericks, Mac Mini Late 2012 (i5, 4 GB ram)

Comment: Did you found any solution to run it fast?

Comment: @BrianBoyle : Did you found any solution to run it fast?

Comment: Nope. I'm pretty sure its as a result of XCode analysing the storyboard every time you open it to make sure there are no inconsistencies in it. One solution I know of is to split your storyboard up into smaller ones. However, this is a lot of work if, like me, you have a large and complex storyboard.

Comment: Same issue da. cant control my anger. Plz da help me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar result when I added a segmented control inside a uitoolbar. It would crawl but only when Xcode was on my external monitor. What did the trick, oddly enough, is making sure the segment control style is set to Bar.

Comment: Thx! That worked for me. Probably a lot calculation effort to do when Segment Control -> Style is "Plain"!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Whenever I opened the storyboard after the inconsistencies message was displayed, Xcode would consume 60%+ CPU and essentially make it unusable.

I (very slowly) found which images were being reported as problems, then deleted them through finder and restarted Xcode. You may also need to remove any references to these images in the storyboard.

Xcode now runs fine - hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the layout constraints on the view.   Storyboard was unusable due to performance until I did this. I'm trying to learn constraints and must have totally jacked them up.

Its under Editor - Resolve AutoLayout Issues - Clear All Constraints in View Controller"

Answer (score 0):

The thing that finally fixed it for me was to disable snapshots in each of the projects that was having performance problems.

> File > Project Settings > Snapshots

Once I had disabled the snapshots, I also nuked all the snapshots.  The total disk usage in my snapshots directory in a fairly short period of time was ~3GB.

The default directory for the snapshots to be stored in is :***~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots***.

Keep in mind that the snapshot setting is set for each project, so you will need to do this for each every project that you are having the performance issues.